Do I need a license or certificate to start an investment firm?
I am a tech entrepreneur. I have a lot of friends who work in the tech industry as well. I would like to start an investment company and ask my friends to invest their money in it. Then, I will find good investment opportunities and suggest them to my friends for investment. (It's not that simple; I just want to give a summary to ask my primary question.)
My primary question is: Do I need any specific license or certificate for myself or my company to do that? If so, what is the minimum requirement for doing that?

Licensing depends on jurisdiction. Where are you going to conduct this business?

@littleadv: CA,USA

What do you have to offer that would cause anyone to trust you with their money?

@keshlam: I am successful in my tech business, and my friends know me well. I want to start with a small circle of my friends and make some successful investments. Then, I will leverage their networks and the reputation we build together to grow my business and establish trust with people who don't know me.

Good luck. I wouldn't go near that proposition. Show a decade or two of successful investment first, and maybe I'd at least listen to your pitch... But I'd rather hire true expertise, and even for that only briefly to set strategy once a decade or so. What makes you more qualified than the pros? Or even as qualified but less expensive? What are you offering that they can't do for themselves? You need a business proposition, not a vague dream that somehow you will succeed.

You're successful in tech business, what makes you think you'd be successful as an investment fund manager? Don't see the connection. How can you be trusted to properly research and vet investments if you can't even figure out the licensing requirements? Just saying....

@keshlam Regarding my own money I totally agree with your concern but that is not what the question is about. In analogy, if someone asks what paperwork is required to open a bakery that is a legitimate question regardless of whether you trust their baking skills.

@quarague: It's a frame challenge. And technically licensing is a legal question, out of scope here. (Flip it around: would you hire someone  to write software that your income depended upon just because they were a successful investor?)

Even 90% of all highly overpaid wall street fund managers can't beat the S&P 500. What makes you think that you can ?

@keshlam: What if it's something like a crowdfunding platform that YOU decide if you like to put some money into that startup or business or not? (I am not gonna reveal my whole idea here but as quarague mentioned above, I am only asking about the paperwork)

Our biggest advantage: We are an AI-based investment firm. If you agree that AI can now (or will soon) outperform humans in writing, singing, and music composition, etc. then you'll see that AI can also outperform traditional investment firms (although they leverage AI, but we are AI experts as they are financial experts)

@best_of_man: You need to prove that claim before anyone will trust you with their money. And you need to beat market rate by enough to pay yourself and still leave an improved result for the customer, which is not easy. And why do you think the companies which have tried assisted investment didn't hire the h st experts they could find? You are making a metric buttload of assumptions here, and customers aren't going to have any interest in betting in your assumptions. You are asking them to accept higher risk for possible higher gain, with no way to quantify either; unattractive.

BTW, speaking as someone who is also in the computer industry, it sounds awfully like you are betting on hype and hope. Today's mist ballyhooed AI systems are glorified autocorrect, good at producing plausible nonsense which looks like real answers. Better will be achieved, but at the moment it's still climbing the hype curve.

I don't think this question is sufficiently detailed to provide an answer.  The specific licenses needed depend on the type of advice being provided, the types of investment opportunities being offered, the jurisdictions where you'll operate, whether you're operating for fees or commission, etc.
